# Does the word "object" have any special meaning in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

Adobe Dreamweaver highlights the word `object` in PHP sources and I'm wondering why. It's definitely not the name of the generic class, which is `generic` (Edit: sorry, it's actually `stdClass` not `generic`, which I always define myself in all projects).

And as you might have guessed it's not easy to google for answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` is a data type in PHP. You typically find it in statements that [cast stuff to objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). Additionally, passing an object to [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) causes it to return the string `'object'` (it's not a keyword, it just tells you that it's an actual PHP data type).

The "generic" class in PHP is `stdClass`. I haven't heard of `generic` being a PHP keyword, ever.

Comment: You're welcome. After posting what ended up to be two nonsense answers in a row just now, I'm just glad I'm making sense again... it's late :P

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php does not include "`object`" (nor "`generic`", actually; maybe you mean [`stdClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)?).

Comment: BoltClock has posted the correct answer (see above): `object` is used in typecasts